# Geting error when installing custome module in joomla 2.5.8

Tags: module, joomla2.5

I am trying to learn creating module for joomla 2.5.8 as per joomla 2.5's documentation but not able to install it properly. while i am installing the module.. it is displaying me error

**error**

Jfolder::Create:could not create directory

Warning: Failed to move File.

the source i am using to learn creating module is

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Module_for_Joomla_2.5

and i had not make any changes from my side... i had just follow as per site instruction. even i put whole code as it is in respected file and also give name to file as in site instruction. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you have incorrect permissions set on folders. Log in to admin panel, then choose Site -> System infromation -> Directory Permissions and check them.

Comment: http://localhost/joomla/logs (Log directory) Unwritable 
http://localhost/joomla/tmp (Temp directory) Unwritable

Only these two are unwritable all another are writable.

Comment: These should be writable. Glad that helped.

Comment: how could i make that writable?

Comment: I noticed "localhost" in your path. Are you using Windows? If so these directories should be writebale, because Windows does not have directories permissions. If you are using Linux then this will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: hi i had try it from both way... from command prompt and by right click on folder and make setting... but still it displays as Unwritable

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of the mine question by the precious help of  Dmitry Rekun. I had try to make that directory writable in both way but still i was facing the issue that is directories LOG an TMP's permissions are still display as unwrittable. so finally I check the config.php file (THE CONFIGURATION FILE ) and there is the i catch the change in code... the code which was the reason for the remain directory permission unwrittable that is

[image]

After make this code comment i change the code as below and the error get solved.

[image]

So please check configuration.php file also if you get still error as directory unwrittable. :)